# Array.toString() method still printing out null values

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I am trying to stop the Array.toString() method from printing out null values in the array. I am getting all of the correct values I just need to make sure not to print out the null values. I tried to implement an if statement to control this.

```
  if(who.getToppings!= null){
   System.out.println("Toppings: "+ Arrays.toString(who.getToppings()));
  }
```

Comment: There are likely `null` elements in your array - if you don't them displayed, either build the `String` yourself by looping over the array or filter out the `null` values

Comment: So, is `getToppings` a field or a method? Your code is inconsistent.  Also, it looks like you're trying to check to see if the array is null, which won't do anything to stop printing values that are null.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, there are null elements in my array depending on what is read in from the text file.

Comment: @azurefrog It is a method

Comment: `Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(who.getToppings()).filter(x -> x != null).toArray());` ...?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are `null` elements in your array that you wish to filter out, then you can use the following:

```
Arrays.stream(who.getToppings())
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
```

This essentially creates a `Stream<T>` (where `T` is the type of your array), filters out `null` elements, and collects it into a `String` replicating `Arrays#toString`.

Assuming your code compiles, you should be able to call it within your print statement:

```
System.out.println("Toppings: " + Arrays.stream(who.getToppings())
                                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting all of the correct values I just need to make sure not
>   to print out the null values.

You could simply recreate an array without the null elements :

```
Object[] toppingsNotNull = Arrays.stream(who.getToppings())
                                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                 .toArray();
if (toppingsNotNull.length > 0){
   System.out.println("Toppings: " + toppingsNotNull);
}
else{
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method prints null values because you have `null` references inside of your array.
Method `Arrays.toString(Object[] a)` aware of this situation and not blindly invoke method `toString()` from
every object in array to prevent `NullPointerException`. Instead of it `String.valueOf(Object object)` used, that checks if 
object is null before to actually invoke `toString()` on it. When object is null this method return string "null".

toString() method in Arrays class:

```
public static String toString(Object[] a) {
        if (a == null)
            return "null";

        int iMax = a.length - 1;
        if (iMax == -1)
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append('[');
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            b.append(String.valueOf(a[i]));
            if (i == iMax)
                return b.append(']').toString();
            b.append(", ");
        }
    }
```

and valueOf() method in String

```
 public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
 }
```

When you want to print values of array and don't want to see null values iterate through it 
checking for null before to invoke toString() from value:

```
public String arrayToString(Object[] array) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(Object object : array) {
        if(object != null) {
            result.append(object); //calls object.toString() inside of append method
            result.append(" ");
        }
    }
    return result.toString().trim();
}
```